# Can't run bash script in CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have the following `buildspec.yml`

```sh
version: 0.2

env:
  shell: bash
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
    commands:
      - source cicd/app_cicd.sh
      - npm_install
```

Where `cicd/app_cicd.sh` is

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function npm_install() {
    npm install
}
```

But the CodeBuild output shows

```
[Container] 2021/05/23 01:55:32 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/05/23 01:55:32 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/05/23 01:55:33 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2021/05/23 01:55:33 Running command export CICD_ROOT=$(pwd)

[Container] 2021/05/23 01:55:33 Running command source cicd/app_cicd.sh

[Container] 2021/05/23 01:55:33 Running command npm_install
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: line 4: npm_install: command not found
```

Given that I've specified to use bash in the `buildspec.yml` and my shell script includes a shebang, I'm not sure what's wrong. This is of course a contrived example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm_install` must be in same line as your `source`, otherwise they are executed fully independently. So your `source` does not carry over to the second command.

```
version: 0.2

env:
  shell: bash
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
    commands:
      - source cicd/app_cicd.sh && npm_install
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to keep the state between list items?